# Improving Handsontable validation reponsiveness

Tags: jquery, ajax, optimization, handsontable

If I'm doing simple checks like isNumeric the response time is fine, but as soon as I start doing anything more complicated (checking against database if value is valid) then it pretty quickly gets too slow to be useful. ie. 45 seconds for 900 rows, 20 minutes for 25k rows (and then the grid gets buggy)

Here is an example of the kind of check I am currently trying to implement:

```
var BadArray = [];
var GoodArray = [];

isValid = function (value, callback) {
    var bad = $.grep(BadArray, function (e) { return e.Key == value; });
    if (bad != null && bad.length === 0) {

        var good = $.grep(GoodArray, function (e) { return e.Key == value; });
        if (good != null && good.length === 0) {
            var errMsg;
            var data =
                $.ajax({
                    //ajax call setup here
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response == "active") {
                            GoodArray.push(value);
                            callback(true);
                        }
                        else {
                            BadArray.push({ Key: value, RspMsg: response });
                            errMsg = response;
                        }
                    }
                });

            if (errMsg != null) {
                $("#ValErrors").empty();
                $.each(BadArray, function (index, value) {
                    $("#ValErrors").append("Key " + value.Key + ": " + value.RspMsg + "<br />");
                });

                callback(false);
            }
        }
        else {
            callback(true);
        }
    }
    else {
        callback(false);
    }
};
```

Is there anything else I can do to improve this specific example?
Are there any generic tips/tricks for how to improve the response time for validation functions in Handsontable?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have 900 rows with say 10 columns each, that's 9,000 ajax calls! Maybe what you could do is only validate cells that change using this method, and when you need to validate all cells, have a separate endpoint that takes the entire data array, checks each one, and returns an array of all the non-validated cells.

Comment: Is there a way to tell Handontable that you want to be able to do the validation that way? I haven't seen any way to stop it from checking each cell individually.

Comment: There is, I can't find how it's done though. Essentially you turn off the validation onChange and then in the `afterChange` event do either `hot.validateCells()` or `hot.validateCell(x,y)`